# csv to dictionary in specific lists (adding values when duplicated keys)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a csv like:

```
2018-01-31;1;2;4
2018-01-31;0;3;0
2018-02-01;5;6;7
2018-02-02;8;9;10
```

My aim is to get:

```
mydict = {
2018-01-31: [[1], [2,3], [4]], 
2018-02-01: [[5], [6],   [7]],
2018-03-02: [[8], [9],  [10]]
}
```

Note that when there's a 'duplicate' key (such as 2018-01-31) its value must be added to the previous existing values for that key (2,3 in the example). **Edit**: If possible, I dont want to add 0´s.

So far the most similar solution I could find is:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('myfile.csv') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
    od = OrderedDict()
    for row in r:
        # get key/ first element in row
        key = row[0]
    # create key/list paring if it does not exist, else just append the value
    od.setdefault(key, []).append(row[1:])
```

...which result is not even a dictionary. I've been stucked for a while with this thing, thank you very much in advance.

*PS1: Number of Rows/Columns may vary but there will be -always- the same number of columns per row*

*PS2: Unfortunately I cannot use Pandas*

Comment: if possible I dont want to add 0 values. Im using this code for a 3d program, setting up scales for spheres. If scale is 0, the program automatically turns it up to 1, which end up in a wrong data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and `zip`:

```
import itertools, csv
with open('filename.csv') as f:
  data = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=';'))

new_results = {a:[list(filter(None, map(int, c))) 
   for c in zip(*map(lambda x:x[1:], list(b)))]  
     for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])
}
```

Output:

```
{'2018-01-31': [[1], [2, 3], [4]], '2018-02-01': [[5], [6], [7]], '2018-02-02': [[8], [9], [10]]}
```

Comment: You do not need the \ inside of `{}`, `[]` or `()`

Comment: @StephenRauch Where should \ be placed?

Comment: You just do not need the \ if you are inside of any of the above.  Basically the above pairs being open let's Python know that the line will need to be continued.  Using this implied continuation is actually preferred by PEP8: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length

Comment: Almost there... Removing the '\' I'm getting: `{'2018-02-01;5;6;7': [], '2018-01-31;1;2;4': [], '2018-02-02;8;9;10': [], '2018-01-31;0;3;0': []}`Im using Python 2.7 Is that a problem...?

Comment: @Victor Please see my recent edit. Use of the `delimiter` parameter in `csv.reader` is required.

Comment: @StephenRauch Thank you for the clarification. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: @StephenRauch Thank you for the information regarding line breaks!

Comment: YES!!! Thank you both @StephenRauch and Ajax1234 I definitely owe you beers, lunch and whatever!!!! THANK YOU, GUYS!!!

Answer (score 2):

With a loop and `zip()` you can do that like:

#### Code:

```
def split_data(some_data):
    results = OrderedDict()
    for datum in some_data:
        split = datum.strip().split(';')
        if split[0] in results:
            for val, dest in zip(split[1:], results[split[0]]):
                if val != '0':
                    dest.append(int(val))
        else:
            results[split[0]] = [[int(s)] for s in split[1:]]
    return results
```

#### Test Code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

data = """
    2018-01-31;1;2;4
    2018-01-31;0;3;0
    2018-02-01;5;6;7
    2018-02-02;8;9;10
""".split('\n')[1:-1]

print(split_data(data))
```

#### Results:

```
OrderedDict([
    ('2018-01-31', [[1], [2, 3], [4]]), 
    ('2018-02-01', [[5], [6], [7]]), 
    ('2018-02-02', [[8], [9], [10]])
])
```

Comment: Thank you very much @StephenRauch for this answer and your help in Ajax's as well. I finally went thru that one because I was in need for a dictionary, but one again THANK YOU very much! I'll firmly study your solution to understand the whole process.

Comment: @Victor, you are very welcome.  And even though I do like beer, here we only work for the upvote.  So thank you for that and good luck and have fun on your Python Journey.